# How can I get hyperjaxb3 to generate specific JPA tags?

Tags: hyperjaxb

I'm trying to get hyperjaxb3 to generate specific tags like @Index, but I've been unable to find documentation or examples on how to achieve this.
Any pointers or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Frederik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Index` is not a JPA annotation, it's a vendor-specific annotation. You can still add such annotations to the schema-derived classes using the annotate plugin. See [this wiki entry](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/wiki/Adding_vendor-specific_annotations) for example.

Comment: Of course, you're right - @Index is not JPA. And the example you provided works like a charm. Thanks :)